# How to install a service using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I would like to install Google cloud SDK as a service with Jenkins through the plugin. But I didn't find the source on how it should be done. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: In which platform do you want to install the Google Cloud SDK? Windows or Linux?

Comment: In Linux environment. But it would be a good choice if I can get both source details for Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

For installing the `Google Clous SDK` in a `Linux (Ubuntu)` environment using Jenkins do the following:

Create a freestyle Jenkins job and in the build step add `Execute shell` and then add the following script into it:

`#create an environment variable for the correct distribution
export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"`

`#Add cloud SDK URI to the pacakage source
sudo echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list`

`#Import Google Cloud public key
sudo curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

`#Install the SDK
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk`

Then run the job, it will install Google Cloud SDK in your machine.

The login to the machine and run `sudo gcloud init` to get started with the SDK.

For more info follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#apt-get).

Comment: Hello ANIL, I just want to install the Google SDK using the plugin like we have the option to install Git using the plugin by providing the source/scripts to install through Configure system but not through Jenkins shell/ Windows Batch executable. Because installing it through the shell is making it unavailable to other jobs. Even Jenkins is unable to access already existing Google SDK as it is installed under a different user.